# Postgres how to fragment a 100 row result with 10 items each on a single column?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am entirely new to Postgres and I have a query that someone created in the past that gets the temperature of a machine. Now, that usually returns 100 rows so I aggregated the result, and it is messy and long. My sample table looks like these

```
id    temperature    Date
-------------------------
1          10        2020-01-01      
2          10        2020-01-01       
3          11        2020-01-01       
4          11        2020-01-01        
5          11        2020-01-01        
6          22        2020-01-01  
7          10        2020-01-01 
8          10        2020-01-01 
9          10        2020-01-01 
10         10        2020-01-01 
11         10        2020-01-01 
12         10        2020-01-01 
13         10        2020-01-01 
14         10        2020-01-01 
15         10        2020-01-01 
16         10        2020-01-01 
17         10        2020-01-01 
18         10        2020-01-01 
19         10        2020-01-01 
20         10        2020-01-01
```

and my current result looks like these

```
Cooker Name|temperature                                                   |
Psalmonela |[10,10,11,11,11,22,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10] |
```

because this is a JSON aggregate function and results are sometimes go to a 100 rows, is there a way I could JSON aggregate it and show it 10 items per aggregate?

```
  (SELECT to_jsonb(ARRAY(
    SELECT
     temperature
    FROM stations
    WHERE
      station_id = 'c23d77d5-0dc5-40c4-asda-22123132'
      LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
  ))) AS normal_temp1,
```

My initial thought is returning results by 10, and using this offset, however, is there a way I could just merge all those 10 fragmented results into 1 column called temperature? So the result will be vertical?

My current output looks like this

[image]

As a newbie, I added a lot of subquery with the same code but limit and offset everything. So can I merge those columns into one column called **temperature** so it looks nicer, however, they dislike the columns that there are now more columns

This is what the report looks like before.
[image]

Comment: Please show the exact output you want here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, added the screenshots of the previous report and what it looks now. However, they wanted to merge it into a single column like the old one but the results show 10 items like the first screenshot. Is that possible on Postgres?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.